# Cross-Validated SVM as function doesn't run

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to compare the performance of several regression and classification algorithms but the svm function from the "e1071" package won't work the way I'd like it to.

So here is my code:

```
library("mlbench")   
library("e1071")
library("hydroGOF")

data(BostonHousing)
data = BostonHousing
rm(BostonHousing)
data = na.omit(data)

svm = function(j, data){
 ### some preparations
 n = dim(data)[1]
 ### empty vector for CV                                          
 fold_j = numeric(n)
 ### assign numbers for every observation from 1 to 10 for CV                                       
 fold_svm = c(rep(1:10, floor(n/10)), 1:(n%%10))
 ### empty vector for infold CV             
 MSE_infold = numeric(10)  
 ### empty vector for cross validated MSE                     
 MSE = numeric(j)  
  for(j in 1:j){
   print(paste0("SVM ", j))
   ### pick a sample for 10-fold CV
   fold_j = sample(fold_svm, n, replace = FALSE)
    for(i in 1:10){
     print(paste0("CV ", i))
     ### define train data 
     traindat_svm = data[fold_j != i, ]
     ### define test data
     newdat = data[fold_j == i, ]
     ### svm
     svm_model = svm(medv ~ ., 
                     data = traindat_svm, 
                     cost = 1000, 
                     gamma = 0.0001)
     ### predict values for response (medv = column 14) with svm
     svm_pred = predict(svm_model, newdat[,-14])
     ### calculate standardized MSE infold
     MSE_infold[i] = ((mse(svm_pred, newdat[,14])) / var(data$medv)) * 100
    }
  ### calculate MSE
  MSE[j] = mean(MSE_infold)
  }
 MSE
}
```

So what happens if I use my function, say

```
svm(10, data)
```

is that I obtain the following error message:

```
Error in svm(medv ~ ., data = traindat_svm, cost = 1000, gamma = 1e-04) : 
  unused arguments (cost = 1000, gamma = 1e-04)
```

If I execute every command separately and without the function/for loops it works nicely.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance, Niklas

Comment: change the name of the 1st `svm` to `svm_something` that will probably solve the pb

Comment: thank you so much, it worked!